# Want to move text to center but can't

Tags: html, css, helper

I want to move the text on the phone version to the center instead of left.

I tried everything. Nothing worked.. any word of advice?

I tried aligning it to center in media queries but it didn't work, as well as padding. I am missing what's wrong.. help will be appreciated.

```
.nav {
  height: var(--header-height);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav__img {
  width: 32px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.nav__logo {
  color: var(--title-color);
  font-weight: 600;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .nav__menu {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: var(--container-color);
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 12px hsla(var(--hue), var(--sat), 15%, 0.15);
    width: 100%;
    height: 4rem;
    padding: 0 1rem;
    display: grid;
    align-content: center;
    border-radius: 1.25rem 1.25rem 0 0;
    transition: .4s;
  }
}

.nav__list, 
.nav__link {
  display: flex;
}

.nav__link {
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  row-gap: 4px;
  color: var(--title-color);
  font-weight: 600;
}

.nav__list {
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.nav__name {
  font-size: var(--tiny-font-size);
  /* display: none;*/ /* Minimalist design, hidden labels */
}

.nav__icon {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

/*Active link*/
.active-link {
  position: relative;
  color: var(--first-color);
  transition: .3s;
}

/* Minimalist design, active link */
/* .active-link::before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -.5rem;
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: var(--first-color);
  border-radius: 50%;
} */

/* Change background header */
.scroll-header {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 12px hsla(var(--hue), var(--sat), 15%, 0.15);
}

/*=============== MEDIA QUERIES ===============*/
/* For small devices */

@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  .nav__name {
    display: none;
  }
}

/* For medium devices */
@media screen and (min-width: 576px) {
  .nav__list {
    justify-content: center;
    column-gap: 3rem;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 767px) {
  body {
    margin: 0;
  }
  .section {
    padding: 7rem 0 2rem;
  }
  .nav {
    height: calc(var(--header-height) + 1.5rem); /* 4.5rem */
  }
  .nav__img {
    display: none;
  }
  .nav__icon {
    display: none;
  }
  .nav__name {
    font-size: var(--normal-font-size);
    /* display: block; */ /* Minimalist design, visible labels */
  }
  .nav__link:hover {
    color: var(--first-color);
  }


  .active-link::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -.75rem;
    width: 4px;
    height: 4px;
    background-color: var(--first-color);
    border-radius: 50%;
  }

  /* Minimalist design */
  /* .active-link::before{
      bottom: -.75rem;
  } */
}

/* For large devices */
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .container {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
}
```

html

```
<header class="header" id="header">
            <nav class="nav container">
                <a href="#" class="nav__logo">Zatar</a>

                <div class="nav__menu" id="nav-menu">
                    <ul class="nav__list">
                        <li class="nav__item">
                            <a href="#home" class="nav__link active-link">
                                <i class='bx bx-home-alt nav__icon'></i>
                                <span class="nav__name">sub</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        
                        <li class="nav__item">
                            <a href="#vision" class="nav__link">
                                <i class='bx bx-user nav__icon'></i>
                                <span class="nav__name">sub</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav__item">
                            <a href="#info" class="nav__link">
                                <i class='bx bx-briefcase-alt nav__icon'></i>
                                <span class="nav__name">sub</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav__item">
                            <a href="#contact" class="nav__link">
                                <i class='bx bx-message-square-detail nav__icon'></i>
                                <span class="nav__name">sub</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
```

here's an image of what it looks like [original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeWXK.png)

Comment: Where is the HTML? You've only shown your CSS.

Comment: set width:100% in .nav__menu in media query

Comment: CSS on its own, without the HTML it is supposed to apply to, tells us little. Please get into the habit of providing a proper [mre] when asking this kind of question.

Comment: I don't recommend to use "var" in CSS. It can effect the speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SeeTohirul's Answer which is a better Solution - [Using Justify Content](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74733033/4990925)

EDIT - After discussion in the comments, I have amended the code snippet, to move the nav to the bottom and centre the logo.

```css
.nav {
  height: var(--header-height);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav__img {
  width: 32px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.nav__logo {
  color: var(--title-color);
  font-weight: 600;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .nav__menu {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: var(--container-color);
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 12px hsla(var(--hue), var(--sat), 15%, 0.15);
    width: 100%;
    height: 4rem;
    padding: 0 1rem;
    display: grid;
    align-content: center;
    border-radius: 1.25rem 1.25rem 0 0;
    transition: .4s;
  }
  .nav__logo {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}

.nav__list, 
.nav__link {
  display: flex;
}

.nav__link {
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  row-gap: 4px;
  color: var(--title-color);
  font-weight: 600;
}

.nav__list {
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.nav__name {
  font-size: var(--tiny-font-size);
  /* display: none;*/ /* Minimalist design, hidden labels */
}

.nav__icon {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

/*Active link*/
.active-link {
  position: relative;
  color: var(--first-color);
  transition: .3s;
}

/* Minimalist design, active link */
/* .active-link::before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -.5rem;
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: var(--first-color);
  border-radius: 50%;
} */

/* Change background header */
.scroll-header {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 12px hsla(var(--hue), var(--sat), 15%, 0.15);
}

/*=============== MEDIA QUERIES ===============*/
/* For small devices */

@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  .nav__name {
    display: none;
  }
}

/* For medium devices */
@media screen and (min-width: 576px) {
  .nav__list {
    justify-content: center;
    column-gap: 3rem;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 767px) {
  body {
    margin: 0;
  }
  .section {
    padding: 7rem 0 2rem;
  }
  .nav {
    height: calc(var(--header-height) + 1.5rem); /* 4.5rem */
  }
  .nav__img {
    display: none;
  }
  .nav__icon {
    display: none;
  }
  .nav__name {
    font-size: var(--normal-font-size);
    /* display: block; */ /* Minimalist design, visible labels */
  }
  .nav__link:hover {
    color: var(--first-color);
  }


  .active-link::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -.75rem;
    width: 4px;
    height: 4px;
    background-color: var(--first-color);
    border-radius: 50%;
  }

  /* Minimalist design */
  /* .active-link::before{
      bottom: -.75rem;
  } */
}

/* For large devices */
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .container {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <header class="header" id="header">
            <nav class="nav container">
                <a href="#" class="nav__logo">Zatar</a>

                <div class="nav__menu" id="nav-menu">
                    <ul class="nav__list">
                        <li class="nav__item">
                            <a href="#home" class="nav__link active-link">
                                <i class='bx bx-home-alt nav__icon'></i>
                                <span class="nav__name">sub</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        
                        <li class="nav__item">
                            <a href="#vision" class="nav__link">
                                <i class='bx bx-user nav__icon'></i>
                                <span class="nav__name">sub</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav__item">
                            <a href="#info" class="nav__link">
                                <i class='bx bx-briefcase-alt nav__icon'></i>
                                <span class="nav__name">sub</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav__item">
                            <a href="#contact" class="nav__link">
                                <i class='bx bx-message-square-detail nav__icon'></i>
                                <span class="nav__name">sub</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yeah but I want it to.. when the size shrinks the logo goes in center and the navbar goes to bottom

Comment: I want it to be centered in top not bottom.

Comment: I want the logo "Zatar" to be centered top when the size shrinks. and the nav menu to be at the bottom.. the problem is. it won't get centered

Comment: @Beji I've added a second snippet above that 1) moves the nav to the bottom, and 2) centers the logo at the top.  I've added a rule for nav__logo under the media query for _(max-width: 767px)_.  In short, adding _margin: 0 auto_ to this new rule will center the logo on the screen when it's shrunk to that size or lower

Comment: just set the justify-content: center for smaller devices

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is `display:flex` you haven't centered it for smaller devices.

```
.nav {
  height: var(--header-height);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .nav{
    justify-content: center;
  }
}
```

#### This should bring the

```
<a href="#" class="nav__logo">Zatar</a>
```

#### In the middle as you wanted

Comment here and let me know if it is not what you are looking for
I will try again to solve your problem.